Using two different library versions with rpm on CentOS
I am trying to install legacy .rpm packages that we have - they require a certain version of a library (e.g. libeg.so.4) but our current CentOS version uses libeg.so.5, and several system tools need version 5.
I tried exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to a folder where version 4 is located && using ldconfig.
I tried copying and symlinking the relevant libeg.so's in /usr/lib64, to no avail.
I think this is because rpm doesn't actually look at the files in /usr/lib64, but it checks its own database at /var/lib/rpm for the installed versions.
If I install the old version 4, system tools requiring version 5 stop working. If I install version 5, I can't install the legacy rpms.
I thought setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH with directories with the old versions was the way to go here, and that this was a fairly common occurrence. But I am failing hard.
What is a way forward here?
